# How to Load the RecyclerView upon starting to the application automatically?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, adapter

I created a fragment with recyclerview and when I executed the application it doesn't load the data automatically for that I have to move to another view and then come back to this particular view to get the data loaded, I want when the application starts the list in recyclerview automatically retrieves the data from the firestore database.

If my code is required do let know.

Thank You for the assistance in advance.

HomeFragement Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    RelativeLayout mParent;
    //FloatingActionButton addButton;

    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference PostsRef = db.collection("posts");

    private CollectionReference likesRef;
    private PostsAdapter adapter;
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions options;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mUserId, id;

    private Button commentsbutton;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUserId = mAuth.getUid();

        likesRef = db.collection("users").document(mUserId).collection("likes");


        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);

        Query query = PostsRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PostsModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            commentsbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.commenting_button);

         mParent =view.findViewById(R.id.relative_home);
      //  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);




        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new PostsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                PostsModel note = documentSnapshot.toObject(PostsModel.class);
                 id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Log.d(TAG, "String post Id is: " + id);

                Intent gotoClickPostDetailActivity = new Intent (view.getContext(), ClickPost.class);
                gotoClickPostDetailActivity.putExtra("PostKey",id);
                startActivity(gotoClickPostDetailActivity);


                //
               // Toast.makeText(c, "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(HomeFragment.this, "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });







        return view;



    }



    private String getTime(long timestamp){
        long ts = timestamp*1000;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String time = sdf.format(new Date(ts));
        return time;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mauth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference UsersRef = db.collection("Users");
    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.document("Notebook/My First Note");
    private MySharedPreferences sp;






    String currentUserID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sp = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
// currentUserID = mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPostActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                   // fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_post:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_postlist:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;

            }
            return loadFragment(fragment);
        }
    };


    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mauth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToSignInActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            checkUserExistence();
        }

    }







}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: Hey Alex, Code is added , please assist further. Thank You

Comment: You shared too many lines of code. Please edit your question and isolate the problem and please also add your database structure.

Comment: I have edited the code  in the question as required, there is a different collection for users and user posts, I am able to share the screenshot of the datastructure but it kind of aggregated one

Comment: @AlexMamo Hey, help please

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in this line of code

```
 Query query = PostsRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options = new 
FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsModel>()
            .setQuery(query, PostsModel.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
```

PostsRef.orderBy take some time to get result from firebase  but you can set result immediately which cause the problem

Comment: no it is not like that, basically there is a bottom tab navigation, when I start the application, it doesn't load any data from firestore, but when I switch to another tab and then switch back to the same tab , it loads data within 2 seconds. .... please provide the recommendations , thank you